# ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet how do I call addOwner()

Tags: wallets, parity, private-key, multisignature

I'm using the [ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet) but I'm struggling to add an additional owner to the wallet.

I've read in the source code that an `addOwner()` call `has to be sent by wallet`, but I'm unsure how to sign a transaction sent by the wallet as the wallet has no private key.

What should I enter for the Key Password in the screen shot below?

[image]

Comment: which contract did you deploy? https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet/tree/master/contracts/solidity

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, Parity is asking you to select an Account first(which takes JSON formatted file) and use the Key Password for that account. (Please treat your MultiSig wallet as a contract because it is)

Basically, you need to have some account from which you want to execute the contract.

As I understand, you want to create a multisig wallet first(which means to deploy a contract first with its constructor parameters) and then you may want to call addOwner.

If you are trying to call `addOwner` on already existing(deployed) contract, you need an address of this contract and call it using your account.

If you don't have imported account in parity, it will show you the same screen that you have right now, which is asking you to provide JSON file(account) with its corresponding password